# Problema al añadir registro a una base de datos en php

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo este codigo de html y php y llevo varios dias dandole vueltas al tema de por que no me añade los registros que yo introduzco por texto a mi base de datos, cuando introduzco los datos y pulso el boton de añadir, los valores introducidos se eliminan de los campos como si se hubiese insertado todo perfectamente pero no lo hace...
Dejo por aqui el codigo a ver si alguien me puede ayudar

```html
<html>
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<center>
<title>Añadir Libro</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <body background="backg.jpg">
<p style="color:black">Desde aqui podremos <strong><ins>añadir libros
</ins></strong> a la libreria, especificando todas sus caractericticas.
</p>
  <?php
     if (!($link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")))  
     {  
     echo "Error conectando a la base de datos.";  
     }  
     if (!mysqli_select_db($link, "libreria1617"))
     {
     echo "Error seleccionando la base de datos.";
              } else if($_POST['titulo_libro']){
              $autor_libro = $_POST['autor_libro'];
              $titulo_libro = $_POST['titulo_libro'];
              $autor_libro = $_POST['autor_libro'];
        $tema_libro = $_POST['tema_libro'];
        $paginas_libro = $_POST['numeroPaginas'];
        $formatoUno_libro = $_POST['cartone'];
        $formatoDos_libro = $_POST['rustica'];
          $formatoTres_libro = $_POST['tapadura'];
        $estado_libro = $_POST['estado'];
              $sql=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `libro` (`Titulo`, `Autor`, `Tema`, `NumPaginas`, `FormatoUno`, `FormatoDos`, `FormatoTres`, `Estado`)
              VALUES ('$titulo_libro', '$autor_libro', '$tema_libro', '$paginas_libro', '$formatoUno_libro', '$formatoDos_libro', '$formatoTres_libro', '$formatoEstado_libro')") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
          $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);                  
              if(! $result ) {
                 die('Error al añadir el libro: ' . mysqli_error());
              }
              echo "Libro añadido: ".'<br />';
              mysqli_close($link);
      } else {
        ?>     
           <form method="post" action="annadirlibro.php">
              <table width = "400" border = "0" cellspacing = "1" 
                 cellpadding = "2">
              
               
                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Titulo del libro</td>
                    <td><input name = "titulo_libro" type = "text" 
                       id = "titulo_libro"></td>
                 </tr>
              
                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Autor del libro</td>
                    <td><input name = "autor_libro" type = "text" 
                       id = "autor_libro"></td>
                 </tr>
              
                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Tema del libro</td>
                    <td><input name = "tema_libro" type = "text" 
                       id = "tema_libro"></td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Numero de paginas del libro</td>
                    <td><input name = "paginas_libro" type = "text" 
                       id = "paginas_libro"></td>
                 </tr>
            
                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Formato Cartone (1 SI, 0 NO)</td>
                    <td><input name = "formatoUno_libro" type = "text" 
                       id = "formatoUno_libro"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Formato Rustica (1 SI, 0 NO)</td>
                    <td><input name = "formatoDos_libro" type = "text" 
                       id = "formatoDos_libro"></td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Formato TapaDura (1 SI, 0 NO)</td>
                    <td><input name = "formatoTres_libro" type = "text" 
                       id = "formatoTres_libro"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Estado del libro (0 Normal, 1 Reedicion)</td>
                    <td><input name = "estado_libro" type = "text" 
                       id = "estado_libro"></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100"> </td>
                    <td>
                       <input name = "button" type = "submit" id = "button" value = "Añadir libro">
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
           </form>
            <?php } ?>
  </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Desde el movil he observado que estas pasando dos veces la función *mysqli_query()*, podrias eliminar $result, y hacer directamente *if(!$sql)*

Answer (score 4):

Únicamente entra en la condición donde haces el insert cuando falla la selección de la base de datos. Deberías hacer algo similar a:

```
if (!mysqli_select_db($link, "sherlock"))  
     {
        echo "Error seleccionando la base de datos.";
     } else if($_POST['titulo_libro']){
        $titulo_libro = $_POST['titulo_libro'];
        $autor_libro = $_POST['autor_libro'];
        $titulo_libro = $_POST['titulo_libro'];
        $autor_libro = $_POST['autor_libro'];
        ...
```

Por otro lado, la query está mal cerrada, te falta un paréntesis para cerrar el grupo de valores:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `libro` (`Titulo`, `Autor`, `Tema`, `NumPaginas`, `FormatoUno`, `FormatoDos`, `FormatoTres`, `Estado`)
                VALUES ('$titulo_libro', '$autor_libro', '$tema_libro', '$paginas_libro', '$formatoUno_libro', '$formatoDos_libro', '$formatoTres_libro', '$formatoEstado_libro')") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
```

Hay muchos más detalles que deberías pulir, pero como punto de partida te puede orientar.

Comment: +1 por el buen ojo.

Comment: Hasta ahi correcto, edito arriba el codigo pero ahora me da estos errores

Notice: Undefined index: numeroPaginas in C:\xampp\htdocs\annadirlibro.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined index: cartone in C:\xampp\htdocs\annadirlibro.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined index: rustica in C:\xampp\htdocs\annadirlibro.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined index: tapadura in C:\xampp\htdocs\annadirlibro.php on line 29

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: estado in C:\xampp\htdocs\annadirlibro.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined variable: formatoEstado_libro in C:\xampp\htdocs\annadirlibro.php on line 32

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\annadirlibro.php on line 35
Error al añadir el libro:

Comment: Insisto en lo comentado en mi respuesta. Hay muchas cosas que no están bien estructuradas ni resueltas.
El primer Notice por ejemplo acerca de la key numeroPaginas aparece porque no la estás enviando en el objeto POST. Con cartone, rustica, tapadura y formatoEstado ocurre lo mismo.

El warning por otro lado, se debe a que tienes que referenciar la conexión mysql como parámetro: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar:

crea un archivo de "configuración" para la base de datos y incluyelo en tus archivos donde vayas a usarlos:

```
<?php
$DB_NAME = 'mi_db';
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';
$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES 'utf8' ");
?>
```

Después una vez incluyes este archivo en el fichero que trabajas (`include("mi_ruta/db_config.php");`)

usa la siguiente sintaxis:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (columnas) VALUES ('valor')";
$res = $db->query($sql) OR DIE ("ERROR");
```

Y no te tienes que complicar tanto la vida.